# Not able to use setOnClickListener on button through button id in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to use setOnClickListener by the help of Button's id in Kotlin but when I try to do so I am getting an error.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener { }
    }
}
```

XML file activity_main

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
        android:onClick="SelectDateBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/select_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

Here I am getting error in main.kt that btnDatePicker is not defined. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried Build > Clean Project? And Invalidate Caches / Restart if that doesn't help?

Comment: Yes, I have tried these things but it doesn't helps me

Comment: Are you using the kotlin-extension (`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`) ?

Comment: And next to what Gabriele Mariotti mentions, are you not missing this import? `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*`

Comment: If I add this import I am getting an error kotlinx is not defined can you help me in resolving this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires the **Kotlin Android Extensions**.
Add the plugin in the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

And in your class you have to add the import:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Also please note that the Kotlin Android Extensions is now **deprecated**.
You should [**migrate**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) to the new library for [**View Binding**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding).

In any case you can always use:

```
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnDatePicker)
```